# Need to pull Tenant server attributes in timeseries widget to caliculate the temperature based on settings in thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I have a requirement where i should pull the **server attribute for the logged in tenant** based on server attribute settings i need to caliculate the temperature(time series data) in timeseries widget.
We can have a **post processing script** for manipulate the dashboard data. but here i need to get the attribute that is the challange here.

Answer (score 0):

I see no challenge here, there are Filter Types for Entity Alias which enable to retrieve data from the current User or Tenant:

[image]

Comment: Yes i can add the tenant and i am already having the enity alias for the timeseries chart. But now  on the timeseries i need to pull this server attributes in postprocess script. I am new to this thingsboard charts. can you help me how to get the server attributes for the current tenant

Comment: Ok I see now, what's the problem. Unfortunately, it is not possible to retrieve other attributes or telemetries. You can only access the underlying telemetry itself. One workaround could be precomputing the values with rulechains instead of doing so in the post processing function.